# Use KDSoap in C++

Tags: c++, qt, soap

i try to create a client for a soap service in c++, i try with kdsoap, i build and install easily, but i can't get use in my projects
I create the .pro file with qmake -project, and only add the next line

```
 include ( kiosco-touch.pri )
```

In  their file,  i put this content

```
 INCLUDEPATH += \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapClient \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapServer 
 DEPENDPATH += \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapClient \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/KDSoapServer 
 LIBS        += -L/home/user/proyects/KDSoap/lib -l/home/user/proyects/KDSoap/
 !isEmpty(QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH):LIBS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH/home/user/proyects/KDSoap/lib

 include(/home/user/proyects/KDSoap/variables.pri)

 DEFINES -= QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
```

When i execute qmake and make, i don't get any error of compilation, but says something 
"/usr/bin/ld: can not open out file, /bin/kiosco-touch: denied permission”

Redading the Makefile generated, say this

```
 QMAKE_TARGET  = kiosco-touch
 DESTDIR       = /bin/#avoid trailing-slash linebreak
 TARGET        = /bin/kiosco-touch
```

For one reason, try create executable file with bin.

So i will edit the .pro or .pri files for read and create correctly the executable, someone have example with this library, or knows how i will read the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i update the post, finally i can get with work, change the .pri file and now content this.

```
LIBS += -L/home/user/proyects/KDSoap/lib -lkdsoap

INCLUDEPATH +=  \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/include \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapClient \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapServer
DEPENDPATH +=  \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/include \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapClient \
        /home/user/proyects/KDSoap/src/KDSoapServer
```

And too is necessary create enviroment variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as is described by the installation manual.

Comment: Note in windows write the entire path and replace -lkdsoap for -lkdsoap1